# Finding Combination of object list using recursive funciton in python takes time

Tags: python, numpy

I want find the first combination object that sum is equal to target. and end the function.

```
def subset_sum_batches(batches, target, partial=[]):
    qty_sum = sum([q.qty for q in partial]) 
    if qty_sum  == target:      # check if the partial sum is equals to target
        return partial
    if qty_sum >= target:       # if sum is greater than quantity continue
        return  False   

    for i in range(len(batches)):
        n = batches[i]
        remaining = batches[i+1:]
        result_batches=subset_sum_batches(remaining, target, partial+[n])
        if result_batches:
             return result_batches
    return False
```

Arguments-

**batches** is list of objects,

**target** is the quantity to match with sum of object quantity

This program works fine if my object list contains less than 20 to 30 objects. But in a practical situation, the object list is of length 1000 to 2000. Then it takes too much time to find the combination.

Need help to improve code.

Comment: Sounds like a knapsack problem. Yes, it takes time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: my function takes time to find the first combination..

Comment: do you have any idea how to improve this function or any other method to achieve my goal

Comment: You should consider editing a question into your question.

Comment: Research the knapsack problem. See what you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using loop and check the sum of records is greater then target then find the to achieve the target the number is in next objects if yes then continue the loop else break and take new object. for combination.

```
def subset_sum_batches(batches, target):
    partial=[]
    diff=0.0
    for i,start in enumerate(batches):
        if start.qty >target:
            continue
        partial=[start]
        remaining=batches[i+1:]
        if sum([q.qty for q in partial]) == target: # check if the partial sum is equals to target
            return partial
        for j,next in enumerate(remaining):
                partial.append(next)
                qty_sum = sum([q.qty for q in partial])     
                if qty_sum  == target:      # check if the partial sum is equals to target
                return partial
                if qty_sum >= target:       # if sum is greater than quantity continue
                    diff = qty_sum - next.qty
                    partial.pop()
                    flag=True
                    if not any([ diff < q.qty for q in remaining[j:]]):
                    break
        if flag and diff:
            if not any([ diff < q.qty for q in batches[i:]]):
                break
    return []
```